# how to hide advance search by defalt in SmartField Value help in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to hide Advance search in value help by default.
When this dialog opens, by default the category and category description Advance search options appears, I want this to be hidden.

Please help on how to approach this issue.

This is what I have [image]

This is what I want: (Advance search to be hidden, not removed altogether)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have used the Explored-Example from [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield/preview) 
There you can also download the coding. Maybe you need to adjust the paths to the mockdata to get it up and running.

What happens if you try: `sap:filterable="false"` in your metadata.xml ?
Please see also the corresponding [docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3361e270c62c46c9893eaefb2966d62e.html).
There it says:
“We notice that we have set sap:filterable="false" for the CURR property. 
We do this, since we would otherwise also have a currency code search field in the dialog that we wish to avoid (default of sap:filterable is true).”

Now your adjusted metadata.xml from the SmartField example above could look like:

```
<EntityType Name="VL_SH_H_CATEGORY" sap:content-version="1">
    <Key>                                                                                
        <PropertyRef Name="CATC" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="CATC" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Category" sap:text="LTXT" sap:filterable="false" />
    <Property Name="LTXT" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:label="Category Description" sap:filterable="false"/>
</EntityType> 
…
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: No, I want "Advance Search" to be initially hidden, not removed altogether.

Comment: @adirocks27 I also have same requirement, any clue here? Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Please try the following:
Using WebIDE:
With the UI Adaption Editor (right click on project, “UI Adaption Editor”) the property filterBarExpanded can be set to “false”.

Does this help?